# r.js throws an error every time I try to assign a variable in Coffee-Script

Tags: coffeescript

So I'm using r.js to build a bunch of my files -- some of which are Coffee-Script. I am using the Require plugin `require-cs` to handle this.

Here is a look at my Require.js config, a la rjs:

```
rjs.optimize({
    baseUrl: SRC_PATH,
    include: channelMap[channel],
    optimize: 'none',
    stubModules: ['cs', 'tpl', 'less', 'text'],
    exclude: ['normalize', 'coffee-script', 'underscore'],
    CoffeeScript: {
        header: false,
        // since we use AMD, there's no need for IIFE
        bare: true
    },
    separateCSS: true,
    skipModuleInsertion: true,
    // If something needs to be present for tests too and not only for
    // the build step, then add it tools/karma-amd.js instead
    paths: _.extend({
        'less-builder': 'vendor/require-less/less-builder',
        'normalize': 'vendor/require-less/normalize'
    }, rjsPaths),
    wrap: true,
    less: {
        paths: [path.join(BASE_SHOP_FOLDER, 'static', 'zalando', 'css', channel)]
    },
    out: path.join(BUILD_PATH, channel, BUILD_BASE_FILE_NAME + '.js')
}, function () {
    // this needs to be async because less builder uses
    // process.nextTick() to write the file
    process.nextTick(done);
});
```

Even the most simple .coffee file seems to fail violently. E.g.

```
define [], ->
    foo = "hello world"
    return foo
```

throws the following error:

```
the variable "foo" can't be assigned with undefined because it has not been declared before
      foo = "hello world"
      ^^^
```

When I use replace `require-cs`'s `coffee-script.js` with the older version of `1.6.3` everything works just fine.

Comment: How did you install the compiler - can you provide a link / command ?

Comment: That is your r.js config for the optimizer, can I see the main.js file where you specify how your paths work (ie. where is the cs.js and coffeescript.js files should be)

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles BTW. Try to go to [CoffeeScriptDahWebSite](http://coffeescript.org/) and click on `TRY COFFEESCRIPT` and you will see that it is valid code.

From the `define [], () -> code ...`, I assume you are using the CoffeeScript plugin with `require.js`. I am ready to bet your issue is in the `require.js` configuration (which should be your `main.js` file or whatever you named it) since the error you get looks oddly like the JavaScript interpreter trying to run the invalid code you wrote (for JavaScript that is :). Meaning, your plugin is not there at all.

If you give me your require configuration maybe I can edit this answer and help you more.

Cheers!

### EDIT

I see you edited your question, but you provided me the wrong file. What you showed me was the `r.js` optimizer configuration, instead of the `main.js` which specifies how `cs.js` and `coffee-script.js` files are loaded.  The error might be in your optimizer, but I can't know without seeing your other config.

A reiteration of that, show me the entry point of your program, the `data-main` that is loaded in your HTML.

Comment: Yeah, good call, I am using require! Let me edit my original question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to recreate the issue:

```
$ cat ./etc/temp1.coffee
define [], ->
  foo = "hello world"
  return foo

$ coffee --version
CoffeeScript version 1.7.1

$ which coffee
/home/dev/.nvm/v0.10.23/bin/coffee

$ coffee -cp ./etc/temp1.coffee
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  define([], function() {
    var foo;
    foo = "hello world";
    return foo;
  });

}).call(this);

$ coffee -cpb ./etc/temp1.coffee
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
define([], function() {
  var foo;
  foo = "hello world";
  return foo;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with my previous version of `1.7.1`. Someone Beautified it and broke everything. Everything works as advertised when I go out of my way to get coffee-script.js from http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js